# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "app.css" at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: css, node.js, express, mongoose

```
app.get("/my/:id",isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
User.findById(req.params.id,function(err,user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/");
    }else{
        console.log(user);
        res.render("profile",{user:user});
    }   
});
```

});

This is my code and my css file doesn't load on this page while it does on other pages

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: value `app.css` is transferred to the db query (`User.findById(...)`) that only accepts the value that can be casted to ObjectId.

Comment: can you tell me the solution then please help ?

Comment: Well, I don't really know what you're trying to do. But what I see is that you're sending the request to /my/app.css which is obviously not your aim (:id is being used to find the user in the database).